# Set pageX for initMouseEvent() in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, mouseevent, mousemove

I'm writing a JS method that will simulate a dragAndDrop action. This is to test a plugin that's basically a slider. The simulated action works in every browser I want to test in except for IE9.

This is the method

```
function dragandDrop(id, className, clientX, clientY, distance){
    var mousedown = document.createEvent("MouseEvent"),
        mouseup   = document.createEvent("MouseEvent"),
        elem      = document.getElementById(id),
        result    = [],
        elems     = elem.getElementsByTagName("*"),
        k         = 0,
        i,
        interval;

    for(i in elems){
        if ((" "+elems[i].className+" ").indexOf(" " + className + " ")>-1){
            result.push(elems[i]);
        }
    }

    mousedown.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, clientX, clientY, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null);
    result[0].dispatchEvent(mousedown);

    interval=setInterval(function(){
        k++;
        iter(k);
        if(k===distance){
            clearInterval(interval);
            mouseup.initMouseEvent("mouseup", true, true, window, 0, clientX+k, clientY, 220+k, 400, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null);
            result[0].dispatchEvent(mouseup);
        }
    },100);

    function iter(y){
        var mousemove=document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
        mousemove.initMouseEvent("mousemove", true, true, window, 0, clientX+y, clientY, clientX+y, clientY, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null);
        result[0].dispatchEvent(mousemove);
    }
}
```

The problem is that in IE9 `initMouseEvent()` doen't set the pageX/Y values, and those values are read-only. They would probably always be equal to the clientX/Y values. The plugin uses pageX/Y so i need to set them to get the test to work in IE9.

I think jQuery have a fix for this, but I can't really find it in the source. It's way over my head. But at least it can be done.

I just don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding jQuery, somethimes it's hard to see the most obvious answers...

```
(function(selector, pageX, pageY, distance){
    var $elem     = $(selector),
        k         = 0,interval,
        mousemove = $.Event("mousemove"),
        mousedown = $.Event("mousedown");
        mouseup   = $.Event("mouseup");

    mousedown.pageX = pageX;
    mousedown.pageY = pageY;
    $elem.trigger(mousedown);

    interval = setInterval(function(){
        k++;
        moveMouse(k);
        if(k === distance){
            clearInterval(interval);
            mouseup.pageX = pageX + k;
            mouseup.pageY = pageY + k;
            mouseup.screenX = pageX + k;
            mouseup.screenY = pageY + k;
            $elem.trigger(mouseup);}
        },100);

        function moveMouse(i){
        mousemove.pageX = pageX + i;
        mousemove.pageY = pageY;

        $elem.trigger(mousemove);}

    })(selector, offsetX, offsetY, x);
```